# Parameterized recipe in makefile?

Tags: bash, makefile

I have a file "ORIGINAL", which, if updated, I would like to copy, modify, and distribute to a few places on the drive.  The modification is made by a little bash script which takes one parameter, a parameter unique for each spawned remote file.

In my Makefile, I can do this with a separate rule/recipe for each parameter, like so:

```
parameters = AWK BAT CAT DOG

$(DEST_FILE_AWK) : $(ORIGINAL)
    ./copyAndModify "AWK"     ## Creates $(ORIGINAL)_AWK, substed copy of ORIGINAL
    mv - f $(ORIGINAL)_AWK $(DEST_FILE_AWK)

$(DEST_FILE_BAT) : $(ORIGINAL)
    ./copyAndModify "BAT"     ## Creates $(ORIGINAL)_BAT, substed copy of ORIGINAL
    mv - f $(ORIGINAL)_BAT $(DEST_FILE_BAT)
```

The dereferenced values of `DEST_FILE_AWK` and `DEST_FILE_BAT` have nothing to do with each other, but other than that, the two recipes above are exactly the same with the only difference the parameter, so I can't help but want to merge them into one super rule/recipe with a multiple target rule line.

But I just can't make it happen.  I've tried all kinds of `foreach()` and other stuff in the target section of the rule, but the problem is that no matter what, I can't get the value of the parameter into the *recipe* part.

Is there a way?

Comment: how do `$(DEST_FILE_AWK)` & `$(DEST_FILE_BAT)` look like after variable expansion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information provided here the best you can do (assuming you're using GNU make) is an eval/call combination.  As anishsane suggests, depending on the value of the DEST_FILE_* variables it might be possible to do something simpler.

But this should work:

```
define COPY_TO_DEST
$$(DEST_FILE_$1) : $$(ORIGINAL)
        ./copyAndModify "$1"
        mv - f $$(ORIGINAL)_$1 $$@
endef

parameters = AWK BAT CAT DOG

$(foreach P,$(parameters),$(eval $(call COPY_TO_DEST,$P)))
```

Comment: To be fair `eval` is probably the most advanced topic described in the GNU make manual: understanding it requires reading and understanding a significant portion of the rest of the manual.  Plus, the GNU make manual is not really a reference manual, designed for "looking through".  It's a user's manual designed to be read from the beginning to the end and learning all about how to write makefiles and use make in an orderly fashion.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without `$(eval)`, at least in gnu make :)

1. Start with one recipe that specifies all of the targets, i.e. the list of targets is on the left side of the recipe. Let's assume we have a variable that holds the names of all these targets.
2. Now observe that *both* functions and variables will be evaluated separately for a given recipe as it gets expanded for each of the targets. Recall that, say `$@` is just a variable, and will be substituted separately for each target. Function calls behave the same.
3. Provide a list of types, and a list of `type:target` pairs. I presume that there's no need to put the targets into separate variables like you did (`$(DEST_FILE_AWK)` etc).
4. The `TARGET_FOR_TYPE` function takes the pairs and the types and generates a list of destination files.
5. The `TYPE` variable is assigned once for each target, computed by the `TYPE_FOR_TARGET` function. That way the repeated function call doesn't pollute the recipe :)

Note that the `DESTINATIONS` list contains plain filenames, without any further indirection.

```
types = AWK BAT
ORIGINAL = an_original
DESTINATIONS = \
    AWK:dest_for_awk \
    BAT:dest_for_bat

TARGET_FOR_TYPE = $(patsubst $(1):%,%,$(filter $(1):%,$(DESTINATIONS)))
TYPE_FOR_TARGET = $(patsubst %:$(1),%,$(filter %:$(1),$(DESTINATIONS)))

# Usage example for the functions above:
$(info type:   $(call TYPE_FOR_TARGET,dest_for_awk))
$(info target: $(call TARGET_FOR_TYPE,AWK))
$(info $())

DEST_FILES = $(foreach type,$(types),$(call TARGET_FOR_TYPE,$(type)))

all: $(DEST_FILES)

$(DEST_FILES) : TYPE=$(call TYPE_FOR_TARGET,$@)
$(DEST_FILES) : $(ORIGINAL)
    @echo ./copyAndModify $(TYPE)
    @echo mv - f $(ORIGINAL)_$(TYPE) $@
```